# Can I move a Perforce label from one revision to another?

Tags: perforce

I'd like to have a "LAST_KNOWN_GOOD" label that points to the latest database that passed nightly regressions (done automatically by the regression script).  The idea being that folks can just sync to that label when the head of tree is broken.

So, the same label spec would get updated over and over.  I'm not seeing anything obvious on how to do this in the perforce doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 labelsync -l LAST_KNOWN_GOOD
```

It's really as simple as that.  As long as the label isn't locked, and the label already exists.

The `p4 label` command can create a label.

You can always learn more about any `command` by typing `p4 help command`

Comment: That's totally it.  I didn't even know that command existed...I was still dorking around with the "p4 label" command.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the label is not locked, you can change the contents of the label. Have a look at the 'p4 labelsync' command.